# Where can I get historical data for crypto currencies with one minute interval?

Tags: historical-data

Where can I get historical data for crypto currencies with one minute time intervals?

I tried to use CCXT, but the exchanges I tried have minimum 5 minute interval or some other limits.

Answer (score 6):

There is plenty of OHLCV 1-minute data on my [cryptoarchive.com.au](https://www.cryptoarchive.com.au) along with tick data as well.

Comment: Huge gaps in the data. Would prefer data where there has been an effort to fill in every minute ohlcv rather than having several hour gaps.

Comment: @Ozymandias The data is actually vetted and 1-min OHLCV has expected for lower volume currency pairs where there were no trades during those minutes.
Nevertheless, I'll think about adding a version with padded data rows if that would be helpful. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

## Short answer

You will have to build it yourself.

## Reference to StackExchange question regarding data sources to build it.

[What are the most comprehensive APIs for cryptocurrency market data?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/60134/what-are-the-most-comprehensive-apis-for-cryptocurrency-market-data)

## Example Resources ( I have no affiliation, just first result on google)

1. https://www.coinapi.io/

[image: https://www.coinapi.io/]

Answer (score 1):

Many of the exchanges only have five minute minimums, so simply retrieving the one-minute candle would be impossible with a simple API call. However, you can set up a a program (using CCXT) that polls the exchanges every minute and collects all the relevant data that you may need. From there, you can recreate the one-minute candle that you desired initially.

Another option is to use the [CoinMarketCap API](https://coinmarketcap.com/api/). There is a cost to this, but the simplicity and accuracy may be worth it, depending on your application.

Additionally, you can find a 5 year history of CoinMarketCap data [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/CryptoMarkets/comments/988u1t/i_have_5_years_of_coinmarketcapcom_crypto_price/), for free.

Answer (score 0):

Here you can find a set with the BTC data. May still help:[Kaggle Historical Data BTC at 1-min intervals](https://www.kaggle.com/mczielinski/bitcoin-historical-data)

Answer (score 0):

[Trading Strategy](https://tradingstrategy.ai/) is a new service for technical trading on [decentralised exchanges](https://tradingstrategy.ai/trading-view/exchanges). We publish [one minute historical OHLCV candles as Parquet files](https://tradingstrategy.ai/trading-view/backtesting) for 100+ exchanges.

Disclaimer: I am the author of the service.